# Object #<EventEmitter> has no method 'storeBuffer'

Tags: file, file-upload, meteor, npm

Apologies for how trivial this may be and formatting. Link to package github: https://github.com/CollectionFS

I'm following the Store a File From the Server example.

In lib/collections.js I have:

```
    Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
        stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("imagest", {path: "~/uploads"})]
    });
```

In server/test.js:

```
  var myText = 'Hello world, I wrote this..:)';
  var buffer = Buffer(myText.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
      buffer[i] = myText.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  Images.storeBuffer('serverFile.txt', buffer, { 
      // Set a contentType (optional)
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      noProgress: false,
      // Attach custom data to the file  
      metadata: { text: 'some stuff' },
      // Set encoding (optional default 'utf-8')
      encoding: 'utf-8'
  });
```

The error is thrown at the storeBuffer call. I've tried a few variations of saving a file from a server but I would really like to use this package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This source](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/107#issuecomment-30066776) states that the method storeBuffer should be available or FS.File.setDataFromBuffer in the devel branch, but both don't work for me.

But I found a solution by reading the source-code of FS.File:

```
file = new FS.File()
    file.attachData buffer, {type: "text/plain"}, ->
        Images.insert file
```